# QgsComposerItem error when runnning on Debian instead of windows

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, linux, debian

I have the following script which has worked on Ubuntu 16.04 and Windows but not on Debian.

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtSql import *
from PyQt4.QtXml import QDomDocument
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *

qpt_file = "a4_vertical.qpt"
output_html = "<html><body>test</body></html>"
if QGis.QGIS_VERSION_INT > 20400:
    renderer = iface.mapCanvas().mapSettings()
else:
    renderer = iface.mapCanvas().mapRenderer()

c = QgsComposition(renderer)

qpt_file_dom = QDomDocument()
qpt_file_dom.setContent(QFile(qpt_file), False)
c.loadFromTemplate(qpt_file_dom, None)
c.refreshItems()

composerMap = c.getComposerMapById(0)

composerLabel = c.getComposerItemById('HEADER')
composerLabel.setText(output_html)
```

When running the code on Debian I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/tmpB8icUm.py", line 26, in <module>
    composerLabel.setText(output_html)
AttributeError: 'QgsComposerItem' object has no attribute 'setText'
```

I tried to solve this based on this issue which is 6 years old:
https://issues.qgis.org/issues/3236

It works when I add `composerLabel.__class__ = QgsComposerLabel`.

But when I'm trying this with `QgsComposerFrame` as follows:

```
table_frame = comp.getComposerItemById('HTML_FRAME_1')
if not isinstance(table_frame, QgsComposerFrame):
    table_frame.__class__ = QgsComposerFrame
table_frame = table_frame.multiFrame()
```

I get the `AttributeError`:

```
AttributeError: 'QgsComposerFrame' object has no attribute 'multiFrame'
```

I'm running Qgis 2.14.18-Essen on Debian Stretch.

QGIS version information:

```
QGIS version: 2.14.18-Essen
QGIS code branch: Release 2.14
Compiled against Qt: 4.8.7
Running against Qt: 4.8.7
Compiled against GDAL/OGR: 2.1.2
Running against GDAL/OGR: 2.1.2
Compiled against GEOS: 3.5.1-CAPI-1.9.1
Running against GEOS: 3.5.1-CAPI-1.9.1 r4246
PostgreSQL Client Version: 9.6.3
SpatiaLite Version: 4.3.0a
QWT Version: 6.1.2
PROJ.4 Version: 493
QScintilla2 Version: 2.9.3
```

I tried run this code under Ubuntu 16.04 and Windows 7 and there it runs without problem.